# Countif Function in VBA with Dynamic Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

### I am trying write a CountIF formula that uses a dynamic criteria to count from a fixed range. Below is the code I was trying to make work:

```
Dim Flow As String

j = 5
For i = 1 To 13
    Flow = Cells(2, j)
    Cells(6, j).Formula = "=COUNTIF($E50:$E100,Flow)"
    j = j + 2     
Next i
```

The results pastes `=COUNTIF($E50:$E100,Flow)` in the targeted cells instead of `=Countif($E50:$E100,E2)`, `=Countif($E50:$E100,G2)`, and so on.

Comment: `"=COUNTIF($E50:$E100," & Flow & ")"` (this is probably a duplicate of over 100 questions)

Comment: You should change your declaration of flow to: `Flow = Cells(2, j).value`

Answer (score 2):

Thank You Johanness. Because the lookup criteria had to be string. I just had to make a slight tweak.

```
Cells(6, j).Formula = "=COUNTIF($E50:$E100,""" & Flow & """)"
```

This seems to do it. Cheers! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Cells(6, j).Formula = "=COUNTIF($E50:$E100," & Flow & ")"
```